# Cordova - menubutton-event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an Android-Application with cordova. The android 4.4 device is connected with a bluetooth remote control.

With the help of the documentation, I am able to catch some buttons, e.g. the "volume-up"-key:

```
document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);

function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {
    console.log("Volume up pressed");
}
```

According to the [cordova-documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html), there are some other Eventlisteners for keys available:

- backbutton
- menubutton
- searchbutton
- startcallbutton
- endcallbutton
- volumedownbutton
- volumeupbutton

I want that the user gets to the settings-page of my application, when he presses the remotes menu-button, but Unfortunately this button doesn't work for me. [Here is the description on the cordova site](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.menubutton.html) and the sample code:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

function onMenuKeyDown() {
  console.log("Menu pressed");
}
```

I have found an APK named "[keytest](https://github.com/chrisboyle/keytest/)", which shows the pressed keys. This app recognizes:

`keyCode=KEYCODE_MENU`

**still, cordova doesn't fire the event... Why?**

[image: Screenshot Keytest]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not documented, but you have to override the menu button to make it work

add this line

```
navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);
```

Then you can use

`document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);`

Comment: Thanks to you because I now remember that I have to open an issue to document this.

Comment: Dont work in Intel XDK. In emulator a click "menubutton" and work. But when compile e put in phone, dont work.

Comment: which cordova version are you using? it was a bug and was fixed, so you might be using an old version with the bug present

Comment: Cordova 6.2.0 still has the bug.  The additional line fixes it.

Comment: It's not a bug, you have to use it as I said. The "bug" is that it's not documented yet.